# Booking.com xpath

Tags: parsing, xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets

I'am trying to add "Hotel name" and "Price" to Excel.

Via google spreadsheet which has function **=importXML** where one can add URL and Xpath to data. The problem is that xpath is not correct for prices and hotel names.

Second day struggle. 
At this page for example: [Booking website](http://www.booking.com/searchresults.en-gb.html?label=gen173nr-1DCAEoggJCAlhYSDNiBW5vcmVmaBGIAQGYAS64AQfIAQzYAQPoAQGoAgM&sid=60bbbf664432d66563dfb6362389e265&checkin_month=9&checkin_monthday=24&checkin_year=2016&checkout_month=9&checkout_monthday=25&checkout_year=2016&class_interval=1&dest_id=-2705195&dest_type=city&dtdisc=0&group_adults=1&group_children=0&hlrd=0&hyb_red=0&inac=0&label_click=undef&nha_red=0&no_rooms=1&postcard=0&redirected_from_city=0&redirected_from_landmark=0&redirected_from_region=0&review_score_group=empty&room1=A&sb_price_type=total&score_min=0&src=index&ss=Baku%2C%20Azerbaijan&ss_all=0&ss_raw=Baku&ssb=empty&sshis=0&nflt=class%3D5%3B&lsf=class%7C5%7C21&unchecked_filter=class) - xpath for prices is:
`//*[@id="hotellist_inner"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[4]/div[2]/strong/b`. Am i Wrong?

Comment: How are you getting the source?

Comment: chrome developers tools -> copy xpath. i thought, maybe it copies wrong xpath, but i checked other things, like page title, i mean static information. And it shows, but when it comes to price and hotel name... it doesn't show.

Comment: The source of the page not the xpath expression.

Comment: ah, my bad. Source of the page loads via importXML query where i add web page url

Comment: Does that handle JavaScript?

Comment: Google spreadsheet doesn't execute js

Comment: Right click and choose view-source in your browser and check if the price is there

Comment: Price is there, checked with enabled and disabled javascript

Comment: `"//strong[contains(@class, 'price availprice')"` should get the prices

Comment: @PadraicCunningham your xpath is incomplete and missing the end bracket `]`

Comment: @AuriellePerlmann, yes that would be a typo. The price is also in the source

Comment: `"//strong[contains(@class, 'price')]//b/text()"` will give you all the prices

Comment: unfortunately price is not working =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the hotel names the xpath you want to use is:

`IMPORTXML(A1,"//*[@class='sr-hotel__name']")`

The price is dynamic and constantly changes - so it is likely being loaded by a javascript endpoint - you could xpath the links to the individual pages and then pull the price from there maybe